# Slanted Text (without using the Text on a Path tool)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

[image]

I need to add a letter to the logo shown in this image, but I haven't had any success using the Type on a Path tool (which is what I used for the gray text above the original logo text).  I can't seem to get the slant right.

Also, the letters are all separate layers, but I'm not sure how this was done.  I inherited this file.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Often when trying to match things, I find it easier to match what's there, then change it.

Matching the angle and skew of "corporation" is fairly easy.

Type the word, all caps, in a similar font (this appears to be some flavor of Helvetica Medium). I eyeballed the size based on the "C". Just free scaled the type until the Cs were close in size.

Using the **Free Transform Tool** with the new text highlighted, click the right side handle of the bounding box and then hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key and drag it up so the new type overlaps the old type. You should be able to get fairly close.

Then just change the type, and scale it if necessary.

You can then delete to the old type (which is outlined and why it's all separate pieces)

[image]

<sub>CS6 animation so cursors and highlights will be different if using a CC version, but the functionality is all the same</sub>

If you are looking to replace the "AES" you may have another issue. Using the above information will get you the same angle as the "AES" However, the angle of the `A` is what is used to align the graphic on its left. There's no additional skew to the "AES". It uses the natural angle of the A. So, replacing the A with an I means you will need to either *introduce* some sort of additional skew, or edit the graphic to match the angle of the new I.

Comment: Wasn't able to get your suggestion to work -- maybe because of CC.  But I got it working with the other suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Type out the text and then select it.

2) Go to Object -> Transform -> Shear... Make the Shear Angle: ~25. Make sure the Axis is Horizontal.

3) Rotate the text.

I don't know why the letters are on different layers. You could just make new layers and put each letter on the separate layers.

Comment: The text has been expanded

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to Photoshop?

It'll be easier for you if things are rotated back straight again to start fresh... It can be done in Illustrator but I personally find it easier in Photoshop.

So I laid down a guide and rotated your screenshot straight:

[image: Straight-up]

Then I painted all around the logo and text. Just because.

The font is some flavor of Helvetica, expanded to outlines, and then Sheared to 15°. I tried Helvetica Neue LT-55 Roman Italic... Looks about right:

[image: IntelliNetX]

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up doing it in Illustrator because I'm not as familiar with Photoshop, but I got it working.